# Can I change the color only of the bokeh in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, bokeh, image-stacking

Say I capture two photos of the same object. The second one with a light pointed towards the camera but away from the lens's optical path so the light creates bokeh. And in Ps, I want to stack these two images and, of the second image, I want the **color of the bokeh** to be changed; without altering the hue of the object.
I think the bokeh image must be on the top and how do I do this?

update:- for @sharkyenergy 's request for the I post these images. Please assume they are aligned. 
       [image]

[image]

I want the color of the bokeh changed while the color of the watch kept intact. Actually I want to match the color of the bokeh to the watch, but that's not always wanted.

Comment: Can you post an example of the two pictures? not sure i follow what you mean.. I would use a hue saturation layer with a layermask to appy it only to the bokeh.. or a blend if, or a curves layer, but it really depends on the actual pictures what techniques you can apply.

Comment: Just make a selection around the watch and invert it.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall but won't it make the whole image change the color?

Comment: No - selecting the watch _then inverting the selection_ will mean that any changes will be applied to everything _but_ the watch.

Comment: oh sorry, I omitted it in my comment. Yeah, as you've said, the changes will be applied **to everything but the watch**. But I want them to apply only to the bokeh.

Comment: The bokeh is so fuzzy that if you try and affect just the obvious hexagonal areas it will look bizarre - there will be an odd shift in colour where your selection fades out.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think image stacking is required at all. To make the image below, I:

- Created a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer
- Selected "Blues"
- Adjusted the hue to get something close to the watch face and also tweaked the saturation and lightness.

I very roughly used a brush to mask out the watch from the Hue/Sat layer and then Gaus Blurred the mask to an extreme so that it applied very gradually. I used a brush at 10% opacity with pure black and white to clean up the watch (where Hue Sat overbled) and the areas near the watch. (as a general rule, it's better to use a lower opacity brush and make more passes than to use a higher opacity and a single pass)

[image]